# Multiple SQL insertions in one query

Tags: php, mysql

HI All, I'm concerned, I have an array coming in from a server. The array is then translated into variables. Such as:

```
$fpage = $_SESSION['scores'];

$score1 = $fpage['0'];
$score2 - $fpage['1'];
//Start of Queries


 // This is what I would like to do, but Its not working: 
$sql ="INSERT INTO Score (ScoreID,ResponseID,AssessorID,CriteriaID,Score,StudentID)"
       . "VALUES ('$rand','$rand2','$adminname','1-22','$score1', '$student')"; 

           $new = mysql_query($sql, $db);
$sql2 ="INSERT INTO Score (ScoreID,ResponseID,AssessorID,CriteriaID,Score,StudentID)"
       . "VALUES ('$rand','$rand2','$adminname','1-21','$score2', '$student')"; 

           $new1 = mysql_query($sql3, $db);
$sql3 ="INSERT INTO Score (ScoreID,ResponseID,AssessorID,CriteriaID,Score,StudentID)"
       . "VALUES ('$rand','$rand2','$adminname','1-21','$score3', '$student')"; 

           $new2 = mysql_query($sql3, $db);
```

My question is, What is the best way of doing this. I have tried to loop the queries, but I could not get that to work. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? error messages? DB not generated?

Comment: First you need to debug your code do that by adding or die(mysql_error()); to each query likst such

mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is a typo in the middle call to `mysql_query` -- you passed in `$sql3` instead of `$sql2`.

Also, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO Score (ScoreID, ResponseID, AssessorID, CriteriaID, Score, StudentID)
    VALUES
        (score1, response1, assessor1, criteria1, etc.),
        (score2, response2, assessor2, criteria2, etc.),
        (score3, response3, assessor3, criteria3, etc.),
        etc.
```

which will only hit the database once for all the inserts instead of once per insert.

Finally, your code appears to be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: You should do as Jon suggested as far as the extended INSERT syntax. It is much faster than issuing a separate query for each row you want to add. You will loop through your array to build the query, then send it all at once. If it's too large for a single query (depends on max_allowed_packet setting), you can break it up into several queries, but still far less than one per entry if the array is large.

Comment: Thank you, the SQL injection aspect will come after my proof of concept. But that will work a lot better. Thanks again!